# How to execute a SQL query against ElasticSearch (using org.elasticsearch.spark.sql format)?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

With Spark 1.6.0 and ES 5.0.0-alpha5 I'm trying to get some dataframe in Spark. I'm using the package

```
--packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-13_2.10:5.0.0-alpha5
```

With

```
sqlContext.read.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql").option("es.nodes", "my_host").load("logstash-2016.10.10/my_type")
```

I can do `printSchema` and see my fields.

However any of these will just hang forever, no exception, no task seem to be submitted to Spark

```
count, first, etc.
```

How can I debug this? Any hint would be appreciated!

Edit:
I'm running elasticsearch in a docker container, to which I can (also) successfully connect via Kibana and direct http rest queries.

Comment: What about your cluster settings ? Where is your spark and es clusters ?

Comment: Can you include the Executors and Environment tabs from web UI? I've never worked with ES so any more code snippet could help me get going and possibly help you. Mind sharing the very simple code to reproduce the issue? Mind describing how to set up an environment similar to yours?

Answer (score 4):

**DISCLAIMER**: I've got no experience with ElasticSearch so mistakes are no exception.

I use the very latest unreleased Spark version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT I built today's morning.

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_112
Branch master
Compiled by user jacek on 2016-12-02T05:06:30Z
Revision a5f02b00291e0a22429a3dca81f12cf6d38fea0b
Url https://github.com/apache/spark.git
Type --help for more information.
```

I use ElasticSearch **5.0.2** that I installed using the official documentation [Installation Steps](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch).

With no changes I ran an ES instance using `./bin/elasticsearch`. No changes to the default configuration.

```
$ curl http://localhost:9200/
{
  "name" : "5PW1rOj",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "nqHBMN7JTw2j8_FD0FZpDg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.0.2",
    "build_hash" : "f6b4951",
    "build_date" : "2016-11-24T10:07:18.101Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.2.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I found the [elasticsearch-hadoop module for Spark](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop#apache-spark). They have just released 5.0.2 so (after some reading about how to work with Spark and ES) I ran `spark-shell` as follows:

```
$ ./bin/spark-shell --packages org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:5.0.2
```

Please note that I knew and still know nothing about ElasticSearch.

When `spark-shell` was up I executed the following:

```
scala> import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

scala> (0 to 10).toDF.saveToEs("spark/helloworld")
```

I did notice that the Spark job executed properly as I could've noticed it in the logs of ElasticSearch:

> [2016-12-02T21:23:02,628][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [5PW1rOj] [spark/jXB6Km6xSjuHxitxjj6Ebw] create_mapping [helloworld]

After playing with ES for some time I ended up with the following indices:

```
$ http http://localhost:9200/spark
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked

{
    "spark": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "hello": {
                "properties": {
                    "value": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            },
            "hello2": {
                "properties": {
                    "value": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            },
            "helloworld": {
                "properties": {
                    "value": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1480709570254",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "spark",
                "uuid": "jXB6Km6xSjuHxitxjj6Ebw",
                "version": {
                    "created": "5000299"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I could find my last `spark/helloworld` using the following query:

```
$ http http://localhost:9200/spark/helloworld/7
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
transfer-encoding: chunked

{
    "_id": "7",
    "_index": "spark",
    "_type": "helloworld",
    "found": false
}
```

And the last but not least, time for Spark's web UI with the Spark job for ElasticSearch query.

[image: Spark's web UI with a job for ElasticSearch]

It *appears* that it works very well from the very beginning with no changes to ElasticSearch or the module.

Ah, I'd have forgotten about `count`:

```
scala> spark.read.format("es").load("spark/helloworld").count
res4: Long = 22
```

[image: count in Spark's web UI]

Comment: Indeed, great example but does not really answer my initial question. I found that I was missing the `es.nodes.wan.only` setting which is needed due to my cluster/network configuration

Comment: While this was not the answer to my nor the OP's question, it is definitely a great effort, so thank you! I'll give you the bounty, but for another reason entirely: I noticed you're the author of Mastering Spark 2.0, which has been my main resource for learning to use Spark. Great job on these notes, it is significantly better than the existing Spark docs!

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I am running the ElasticSearch and Spark instances as Docker containers within Google Cloud. After reading and searching everywhere, I came across this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/cloud.html. The ES Spark connector has a setting called `es.nodes.wan.only` which makes it function within cloud environment such as Google Cloud or AWS. I had the exact same problem as the OP before, e.g. `printSchema` worked but any aggregrates did not work, and this exact setting fixed it for me!

You can configure it when initialising your `SparkConfig`, like this:

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf()
.setAppName("MySparkModel")
.set("es.nodes.wan.only", "true)
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer because it's correct, but I have this feeling that something is missing. Didn't you also supply credentials an such ?

Comment: @eliasah of course there are other settings that I'm configuring, such as the hostname, port and more. However, I'm just highlighting the specific setting I needed to add to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite old, but I will describe the approach that I used to work with ES 5.0 and Spark 2.0 for future references. I think the ES-Hadoop documentation is a bit unclear on what artifact and API to use.

I used `org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:5.0` and the following code:

```
// add to your class imports
import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._

// Use Spark 2.0 SparkSession object to provide your config
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(...).getOrCreate()
// Optional step, imports things like $"column"
import sparkSession.implicits._
// Specify your index and type in ES
val df = spark.esDF("index/type")
// Perform an action
df.count()
```

I assume the situation is quite similar for Spark 1.6 with some minor changes. In particular, you should use `SQLContext` or `HiveContext` instead of `SparkSession`.

Comment: This does not answer the question unfortunately. I'm having the exact same problem as the author: I'm able to initiate a connection with the ES instance (using code similar to yours), but any actual aggregration function (such as `df.count()`) will simply run forever and never return a result.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your use case? Are you running a local instance of ES or you have a cluster? Which Spark mode do you use? Is this problem specific to Spark SQL or it also appears when you try to use RDDs?